# How can you show the date in a gridview as a date only instead of a datetime?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I am pulling in date values from a sql server database using a gridview and and the date gets converted from

> 12/12/2009 **to** 12/12/2009 12:00:00 AM

How do I prevent that from happening ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `ToString()` method with a mask:

```
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

UPDATE:  Just realized it would be easier in your case to do this in the grid view template

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 14):

You can set the date format in the bound column like this

```
<itemtemplate>
<asp id="Label1" runat="server" Label.Text='<%# Bind("YourDateField", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'>;
</asp>
</itemtemplate>
```

Comment: You can also use this same syntax with Eval.  e.g. Text='<%# Eval("OpenedDate", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>' />

Answer (score 5):

set the dataformatstring value to "{0:d}"

Ex:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date_Field" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 4):

Within

> asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAndTime") %>'

Try adding **"{0:M-dd-yyyy}"**

> asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAndTime"**, "{0:M-dd-yyyy}"**) %>'

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.ToShortDateString()` on the **DateTime** Object if you are already manipulating the date in the RowDataBound

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataAnnotations attribute and a DynamicField control; then you don't have to do the same formatting every time you want to format that field.
There is an example showing how to do this here:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-%E2%80%93-getting-started-part-8

Answer (score 0):

when you select the field from the database you can convert it to a string in the select as:

```
convert(varchar, myDate, 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="my_date" HeaderText="Date" 
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="my_date" 
                            DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

In the above mentioned code, `my_date` is the date column of the sqlserver table. The `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` is the main portion of this code to resolve the particular issue of yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < gv_bill_dmd_process_create.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row_fees = (GridViewRow)gv_bill_dmd_process_create.Rows[j];
                    TextBox gv_chk_bill_dept = row_fees.FindControl("txt_gv_DmdProsDuedate") as TextBox;
                    AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender gv_chk_bill_dept1 = row_fees.FindControl("txt_gv_DmdProsDuedate_CalendarExtender") as AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender;
                    gv_chk_bill_dept1.StartDate = fromdate;
                    gv_chk_bill_dept1.EndDate = todate;
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

use this in query where you are getting date field

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,date column name,103) as date
```

ex:`select column1,column2,CONVERT(VARCHAR,date column name,103) as date from tablename`

Comment: Using a SQL convert limits the amount data you get back from the DB.  You're better off with a formatting function.