# how to insert only date into date datatype column database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to insert date into a column in database. I have a label that shows the date. I insert it into a `varchar` column before but it display different result when I sort it. here is the result when using `varchar` :  09/05/2014; 20/04/2014; 21/04/2014...etc...

I get this result when inserting into date type column :  `09/05/2014 00:00:00`.

Here is the code:

```
dim DType as date = CDate(lbldate.Text)
Dim strcommand As String

Dim o As String
strcommand = "insert into tbBooth ([date2]) values (@ddate)"
Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(strcommand, sqlcon)
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@ddate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dtype)
o = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I want it to store only date because when I just ignore the time and use it on my program it give me bad result, like 01/01/1914; 01/01/1936; 01/01/2002.....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So if you want to store dates - use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` column types - **NOT** `varchar`!

Comment: Its a date.  Use the Date datatype, not varchar!

Comment: already. but it also stored the time. what should I do to stored only the date excluding the time?

Comment: @user3567963 If you use the ToDateTime() method, you should expect to get a datetime value. If you need a different kind of value, then use a different method. E.g., ToDate() might be a better choice.

Comment: you can use date data type if you are using sqlserver 2008 and above.
[link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

Comment: I checked the database, It stored only date. but when I called it and display it on the gridview, it's also display the time. I called it using this syntax : select * from tb_Date. does it will be like that when we called the date column?

Comment: @user3567963 More appropriately, the ToShortDateString() might be the method to use. The ToDate() function isn't right for vb.net; not sure how I grabbed that.

Comment: The column might be a `DATE` in SQL Server - storing **only** the date. But .NET only has `DateTime` which always includes the time portion.
[See this other SO question (and its answers!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075754/how-can-you-show-the-date-in-a-gridview-as-a-date-only-instead-of-a-datetime) on how to properly **format** your `DateTime` display in e.g. a gridview to show **date only**

Answer (score 2):

use 'Date' datatype for your column in database. 'datetime' dataype takes date with time.

Comment: you mean u have datatype as date and it still showing full datetime??

Comment: yeah... it's already stored only date but when I called it, it display both date and time.